# Am I not to assume that the author has made an attempt to solve the problem?

Tags: discussion

In a lot of posts on SO, there are questions that ask how to do something without first making an attempt to solve the problem (or at the very least stating what they believe *could* work). Seeing questions like this, I typically comment asking the poster what they've tried (as do many others). I've never had a problem posting these comments, but today I see this:

[image: What have you tried?]

I was under the impression that, when posting a how-to question, you needed to at least *try* to solve it yourself. The wording of that notification only confused me further. Am I wrong to assume they've tried something? A comment like that would not make sense on a question asking why/what something is, but should it really be filtered out across the board?

Comment: `Am I wrong to assume they've tried something?` I mean, that *is* what the error message is telling you, pretty explicitly.  So, according to SO, yes, it's wrong of you to assume that they tried something before asking their question.

Comment: That was just another step of SE against the fight of crap questions (or posts in general). We'll see what the next step is.

Comment: It's quicker to assume that they have tried nothiing.  You then occasionally, (too occasionally), get a pleasant surprise when reading further reveals some test output or, (miraculously), some details of debugging done.

Comment: The "What have you tried?" business only got started because, in certain cases, showing what you've tried is necessary to *provide context*. In other words, when a complete solution is too broad/complicated for our format, you need to show what you've tried to narrow down the question. In cases where this isn't true, and the solution is simple enough, it is just noise to show all of your failures. Leave comments asking for the relevant information you want to know.